# index.php should not show up on the url like facebook?

Tags: php

I have noticed the facebook site showing up url like http://www.facebook.com/?sk=nf
what i understand is there must be a index file = index.php which is working based on the GET variable sk to get contents for its functionality .

can anyone help please?

I have tried to add a link in my page href="?sp=admin" on a page noname.php which is in a folder xxxx along with the index.php

xxxx> index.php
xxxx> noname.php

so when i click on that link it directs to "noname.php?sp=admin" while i want it go to
"index.php?sp=admin"

and my site should show up like this www.xxxx.com/?sp=admin

Comment: The keyword is `mod_rewrite` if you use apache webserver.

Answer (score 0):

you will try like this href="/?sp=admin" it will redirect to index page like  www.xxxx.com/?sp=admin. please add slash

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset On
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteRule ^index.php /noname.php [L]
```

please use this mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess file in your xxx folder

Comment: please use this mod_rewrite rules in .htaccess file in your xxx folder